# How do you display a comment into a mail?

Tags: author

So I want to notify the author (via mail) that his comment have been removed, and which post the comment was related to.

```
    // Mail author when their answer is deleted/trashed
function authorANotification($comment_id) {
  $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
$author = get_userdata($comment->user_id);
       $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
       $headers .= "From: Fustions.com <admin@fustions.com>" . "\r\n";
       $subject = "Your comment has been deleted";  
   $message = "<html><body><div align='center' style='font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4d;background:#F6FAF3;padding:20px 20px 100px;'>";
    $message .= "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='color:#4d4d4d;text-align:left;padding-bottom:20px;width:600px;'>";
    $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:25px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;'>".$sitename."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</td></tr></table>";
    $message .= "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border:1px solid #c4c2c0; font-size: 12px; font-family:Arial;color:#4d4d4d;text-align:left;background:#fff;padding:15px 20px 20px;width:600px;'>";
    $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;padding-bottom:15px;'>Dear ".$author->display_name.",</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td height='1' style='background:#ccc;'></td></tr>";   
    $message .= "<tr><td style='padding:15px 0;'>Your comment: ".$comment->comment_text." - has been removed by an admin.</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td style='padding:15px 0;'>Read about why your comment might have been removed here: **********</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td>Best regards,</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td>Administration - Fustions.com</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</td></tr></table>";
    $message .= "</div></body></html>";



wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
add_action('trash_comment', 'authorANotification');
```

What am I doing wrong? And also, how do I display the title of the involved post?

Thanks!

Comment: We would need to see your entire function and the `add_action()` you are using, to be of any substantial help.

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? There is also a `delete_comment`. Are you sure you are using the right hook?